# select * where id in (....) and all columX are equal

Tags: mysql

Hej folks,

i have to deal with a special problem. First this is the simplified table:

```
 id | A | B
-------------
  1 | a | 1
  2 | b | 2
  3 | c | 1
  4 | d | 1
  5 | e | 3
  6 | f | 1
  7 | g | 2
```

thanks to a quite lame API I get a list of required ids like

```
(1,2,3,5,6)
```

BUT, out of this list i have to select only the rows with a specific *unknown* value in column B. In this example the unknown value would be 1 since the first matched id has a 1 in column B.

As a result I would need the rows

```
1, 3, 4, 6
```

because the *required* row 2 and 6 have different values in column B.

I hope you can follow so far.

The problem is already solved by filtering the result inside the software but i wonder if there is a solution with pure SQL?

The DB is MySQL and i have no chance to change the tables or the API since this a plugin to existing software :(

Thanks in advance! I guess its impossible but to be true my SQL skills are not the best.

P.S.

if the requested ids would be this:

```
 (2,3,5,6,7)
```

the result must be:

```
(2, 7)
```

because the first fetched value for column B is "2"

Comment: So to clarify, you get a list of id's that you need to return. Then, the value in column B (let's call that value X) for the FIRST match on that id, which will logically be the lowest id value out of the ones provided in the list, will then serve as a second constraint, and all rows returned must then ALSO be B = X?

Comment: yep :( 
thats the problem

Comment: `WHERE id IN (...) AND B = (SELECT B FROM table WHERE id=1)`?

Comment: yes that would be possible. but how to determine the subquery id without manipulating the list of ids in the software? i was testing with this but select all rows and delete unnecessary in the software seemed a bit faster. in most cases we are talking about 2~3 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND ColB = (SELECT ColB FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
```

In the inner query (one inside the parentheses), I left the whole sequence intact because I am assuming this is being inserted by a server-side script such as PHP. This way, you can just re-use the same variable.

### Edit

I did not realize the ID's could be in a random order (i.e. 3,2,7,1 and then 3 would be authoritative from that list, not 1).

See this new query which addresses the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND ColB = (SELECT ColB FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5) ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,2,3,4,5) LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: looks like be best and fastest solution! I assume the subquery stops right after it find the value for B? Damn I miss my DB guy :(

Comment: Yep, the "LIMIT 1" clause should make it stop searching after it hits the first match.

Comment: @JustinIurman, that is incorrect because the query needs to be limited by BOTH constraints. Your query will return ALL id's which have column "B" set to the first row's value, regardless of the id's supplied in the original list.

Comment: thats what i thought too

Comment: mmmm so the `IN` operator sorts the value and starts with the lowest? i thought it just graps the first value in the list

Comment: No, it is the ORDER BY operator within the sub-query... In the first query, we used ORDER BY id ASC, which put them in ascending order (and because of the LIMIT 1, would match on the lowest value); the list which it ordered was limited by the IN condition inside the WHERE clause. So, doing IN (3,5,1,2,8) would limit id's to only those 5, and then order them ascending (lowest to highest), taking the first one (which will be "1"). However, the second query, which uses ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,6,1,2,8), puts them in a _specific_ order when it sorts the rows, exactly as is specified in its clause.

Comment: okay thanks a lot! *maybe* i have to do some more Database research  even though I'm just a dump software coder who hates databases. again thank you and a good night (or day, where ever you live) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can approach the problem with a self join.

Join the table against it self on the value of column B. From that select all where the ID is in your request.

Comment: sounds good but also a bit "expensive"? The table has around 40,000 rows with around 10,000 different values for B. could take a while to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery that returns the value of the first (lowest) ID, using LEAST function:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  B = (SELECT B FROM yourtable WHERE ID = LEAST(1,2,3,5,6));
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a4c/1). You might also want to add the condition:

```
WHERE
  ID IN (1,2,3,5,6)
  AND
  B = (SELECT B FROM yourtable WHERE ID = LEAST(1,2,3,5,6));
```

Comment: I think that would only work if it is guaranteed that all of the ID's supplied are present in the database (and this would depend on mercsen's data structure). If it was not guaranteed, and the app was supplied with a list of 0,1,2,3,5,6, it would break the query because there is no row with an id of '0'.

Comment: never ever heard of LEAST :p
so which one is faster (yes i mean in nanoseconds ^^). Yours or Rulans solutions? if I'm right Least is a function that need to be executed to find the smallest value while a simple `B = (SELECT B FROM tbl WHERE id in (1,2,3,4) Limit 1 )` simply starts a search beginning with 1? Besides the list of IDs could also be like `(3,4,1)` then 3 determines the value for B.

i hate this software so much :P

Comment: @mercsen this one should be faster than ruslan solution because it will calculate the least value before performing the query (but if values are just a few, and there's a proper index, speed would be almost the same). But yes, my solution will only work if it is guaranteed that all values returned by your API are present in the database. If you have 0,1,2,3 and there's no ID 0, do you need to return ID=1 or no values?

Comment: I actually did not realize that the id's could be provided in a different order (not necessarily ascending). The first version of my query will only work for a scenario where it will pick B from the LOWEST matched id, not the first one in the list. But see my edit, which will work for that case as well.

Comment: all IDs are present since the list is generated out of this table... dont ask me why or how. I need to return the whole row. 
The problem is the folloing: A user can select different nodes in a tree and can add their ids to this list. I have to load these ids and do awesome stuff with the data. But if i load all ids and B has somewhere a different value the output would be incorrect (but possible) so i need to get rid of all false B values. So we decided that the first ID specifics B